# How to make Flexbox span multiple lines?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to use CSS **Flexbox** properties to make some sort of grid, where the elements may span across multiple lines.

Here's the essential HTML source code:

```
<section class="group">
    <h1>...</h1>
    <section class="item">...</section>
    <section class="item">...</section>
    <section class="item">...</section>
    <section class="item">...</section>
    <section class="item">...</section>
    <section class="item">...</section>
</section>
```

Here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

Within the `section.group`, I want the `h1` to be 100% wide with each `section.item` being 50% wide, arranged in a *n* × 2 grid, where *n* is dependent on the number of inner `sections`, which may change.

I cannot change the HTML, which means I cannot wrap `section.item`s with unsemantic `div`s. I can only use CSS. Here's what I have so far:

```
.group {
   display: flex;
}
.group h1 {}
.group .item {}
```

(not much of a start)

How can I use the **Flexbox Module** to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, make sure `flex-direction` is set to `row` or `row-reverse`, because we want to lay out the items horizontally (left-to-right or right-to-left). But really, `flex-direction: row;` is default so we don’t explicitly need it. It’s just here for beginners.

Then, to ensure the boxes break across multiple tracks, add  `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

```
.group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Now we have to size the items. TLDR:

```
.group h1    { flex: 100%; } /* flex: 1 1 100%; */
.group .item { flex:  50%; } /* flex: 1 1  50%; */
```

If you want to know why, read on. Otherwise, that’s it!

---

By default, the **main size** (in this case, horizontal size, or width) of each flex item defers to the specified value of its `width` property. At first glance, we may want to just declare the widths:

```
/* NOPE!
.group h1    { width: 100%; }
.group .item { width:  50%; }
*/
```

However this is not very future-proof, as we may want to later change the flex-direction if for example we are writing in a vertical writing mode, or even if we merely want to swap the layout. If `flex-direction` is `column` or `column-reverse`, then setting the widths won’t get us what we want. We are really looking to size the **main-size**, which is what `flex` is for.

(This is an extremely basic usage of `flex`, but it is in fact a lot more …ahem… *flexible* …. Read more about the [`flex` shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) on MDN.)

And some more info about flexbox in the [CSS3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-property) and in the [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

Answer (score 4):

My first answer was about using Flexbox to achieve the layout.

In this answer I talk about Grid.

To jump straight to the point, CSS Grid should be used in this situation. Flexbox is intended for one-dimensional layouts, or when wrapping rows (or columns), wrapping can happen arbitrarily, at any point beyond our control.

When we want complete control over both rows *and* columns. CSS Grid is our solution. CSS Grid is also a lot easier, because we only need to style the grid container, not any of its children. There are exceptions of course, like our heading.

```
.group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.group h1 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

## Let’s break it down.

### `display: grid;`

This is self-explanatory. It sets up the grid container.

### `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`

We want 2 columns, with `1fr` each, where a `fr` unit is “the remaining space”. In other words, the two columns share an equal amount of the remaining space. There are many ways to write this.

- `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` is what we used, but we could have written
- `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);`, or
- `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`, or even
- `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;`

It just depends on how often you like to change your code. Later down the road if we want a 3-column layout, it could either be

- `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`,
- `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.33%);`, or
- `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr`, or
- `grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%`.

Or let’s say we still want 2 columns, but we want the left to be half as big as the right—a one-to-two ratio:

- `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr`
- `grid-template-columns: 33.33% 66.67%`

The `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` are very complex properties that I still don’t understand fully. Don’t even get me started on automatic sizing, flexible breadths, and size ranges.

Let it be stated that although `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);` is also a valid style, it’s not what we want here since `auto` sizes the columns based on their content, and we aren’t guaranteed that each will be 50% wide.

### `grid-column: 1 / -1;`

This one looks weird, but it’s easy to learn. `grid-column` is shorthand for `grid-column-start / grid-column-end`, where the integers number the lines that define the columns. You can also use names, but that would be overkill for a layout as simple as ours.

1. The first line, at the start of the grid, is `1` (not zero).
2. In our grid, `2` is the line between the columns, and
3. `3` is at the end.

In general though, negative numbers count backwards from the end. So in our 2-column grid, `-1` is the same as `3`, but in a 3-column layout, `-1` would be equivalent to `4`.

We want our header to be the full-width no matter how many columns we have, so it starts at `1` and ends at `-1`.

*(Note: be aware that your preprocessor might interpret the slash as a division symbol, compiling to `grid-column: -1;`. Not cool. So in Less at least, I would escape a string literal. I can’t speak for Sass.)*

```
grid-column: ~'1 / -1'; // compiles to `grid-column: 1 / -1;`
```